# JButton makes everything on my panel disappear

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have encountered a problem with my simple Java program. Here you can see what I have made:

```
public class første_prosjekt {
   int numbers[] = new int[9];
   int total;

public første_prosjekt(){       
    frame();
}

public void frame(){        
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton b0 = new JButton("=");

    b1.setBounds(125, 250, 75, 75);
    b2.setBounds(250, 250, 75, 75 );
    b3.setBounds(375, 250, 75, 75);
    b4.setBounds(125, 350, 75, 75);
    b5.setBounds(250, 350, 75, 75);
    b6.setBounds(375, 350, 75, 75);
    b7.setBounds(125, 450, 75, 75);
    b8.setBounds(250, 450, 75, 75);
    b9.setBounds(375, 450, 75, 75);
    b0.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "THE BUTTON WORKED FLAWLESSLY");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Second message");
            total = +1;
        }
    });

    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 added");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, total);
        }
    });

    b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "3 added");
        }
    });

    b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "4");
        }
    });

    panel.add(b1);
    panel.add(b2);
    panel.add(b3);
    panel.add(b4);
    panel.add(b5);
    panel.add(b6);
    panel.add(b7);
    panel.add(b8);
    panel.add(b9);
    frame.add(panel);       
}

public static void main(String[] Args){
    new første_prosjekt();      
}
```

}

It might be bad set up, but that is not the point. When I added the `JButton b4` everything on the panel disappear. 
Also for some reason after I have added a little I have to compile it a couple of times before it works. 
And yes, I am new to this.

Hope to get some help!

- Thanks :)

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Take `frame.setVisible(true);` move to under `frame.add(panel);`

Answer (score 1):

Swing components must not be modified outside of the Event Dispatch Thread. Edit the code in your main function like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new første_prosjekt());
```

Also, avoid using `null`-layout. Use a suitable layout manager instead.

Comment: This is defintaly advice the OP should follow and implement, but it won't solve the underlying issue and using a layout manager might even make it more consistent